# C : array of struct (which holds an int and another array of another struct)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
struct dataStruct {     const char* s;     int num; }; 

struct Final_struct {     int n;     dataStruct a[]; };
```

Now the problem occurs when I try to initialize the Final_struct as followed:

```
const Final_struct Example[]= {
                                {100, { {"age", 20}, {"iq", 120}, {"bmi",26} } },
                                {100, { {"age", 36}, {"iq", 145}, {"bmi",22} }}
};
```

It's a c code, and when I try to compile it gives the compiler error :

`Fields of the object can not have arrrays of size 0`

Any suggestions?

thank you.

Comment: You should have gotten tons of compiler errors, not just one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dataStruct a[]` defines the member of the struct as an array of size `0`. This is practically useless. You need to specify its size in the definition of the `struct` because the compiler needs to know the size of the entire `struct` in advance.

Or, you can simply declare the field as `dataStruct *a` and then the array itself will not be contained in the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C, what is `string` ? Why do you expect to be able initialize it from what looks like other variables?

Try `const char *` for `s`, and initialize from quoted string literals.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget quotes on your strings?

"age"

Comment: thanks for noticing, but that is not the problem ... I made an error while writing the example. will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting double quotes around your string constants?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

Try:

```
/* note the explicit array size for a[] */
struct Final_struct {     int n;     struct dataStruct a[3]; };
```

Comment: Thank you. I seriously doubt my coding capabilities sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

the array 'a' which is declared inside the structure named Final_struct should have the size. with out know the size of that variable the compiler can't assign the memory for that variable. so you should allocate the size first...